# Spring Servlet mapping confusion

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Basically I have a mapping like `/A/B/something` whose mapping is given as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/B")
public class BController {
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView func1()....
```

func1() gets called. 
In web.xml, the definition is given only for A.
So its something like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>A</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>A</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/A/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

In applicationcontext.xml, there is component scan for this BController.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="BController" />
```

So, my question is:

- How does servlet know to move from `/A`'s mapping to `/B`'s mapping. How
  is `func1()` getting called?
- If applicationcontext.xml directly takes `/B` into
  consideration, why is func1() not getting called after I delete `/A` from the call ( If I call `/B/something` from my application, it
  gives an error. )?

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spring DispatcherServlet is a central component which dispatches all requests to the registered handlers (the controllers). In your case, it has been mapped to the /A relative path:

```
 <url-pattern>/A/*</url-pattern>
```

The line above basically tells the web container, that each and every request which starts with /A relative to the host should be handled by the spring DispatcherServlet. From this point further, it's up to Spring to handle the mappings.

```
 @RequestMapping("/B")
```

The line above adds up to the DispatcherServlet, so to this point it maps to /A/B

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/something")
```

Similar to the previous request mapping, the line above adds up to the class level mapping, so the method func1 will finally be called with the following call:

```
 POST <yourhost>/A/B/something
```

Hope that helps.